# how to avoid interface method in my class

Tags: c#, oop

I have 4 clients  but 3 clients want `add(int a, int b)` method but my new 1 client want `add(int a, int b, int c)` method, I run my project its show me below error how to avoid this error, I don't want implement `add(int a, int b, int c)` my old classes,

> does not implement interface member `CheckFTP.iinterface.add(int, int, int)`

```
interface imyInterface
{
    void add(int a, int b); // Implement 2015
    void add(int a, int b, int c); // implement 2016
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to implement interface, remove it from declaration

Comment: 1 client want  void add(int a, int b, int c), but my old classes also show this error , how to avoid this method

Comment: If the second method would only be used in 1 client, remove it from the interface and implement it only in that client

Comment: Two separate interfaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces can inherit from other interfaces. As others already suggested, create two interfaces, like

```
interface imyInterface
{
    void add(int a, int b); // Implement 2015
}
interface imy2016Interface : imyInterface
{
    void add(int a, int b, int c); // implement 2016
}
```

Now your new classes can still be used in the old system (as they still implement the old interface), and your old classes need not be changed.

Comment: @addikhan note that you don't *need* one interface to implement the other, you can do `Class : IMyInterface, IMy2016Interface` and keep the two interfaces totally independent of each other (which is a good idea in almost all situations).

Answer (score 1):

If you define methods in an interface, all clients that implement that interface 'must' implement all methods, even if there is no functional code (it could throw MethodNotImplemented exception)

You could expose a secondary Interface that only defines the single, updated method and use this on certain clients.

Alternatively, you could code the client without reference to an interface, or code to the existing interface and add the new method without having to adhere to the contract. Clients are not simply restricted to the methods defined in the interface, although generally that is the way you would work.

Clients can implement more than 1 interface if required.

Comment: Yes, best way would be to create a 2nd interface (that can inherit from the original one if both add methods are needed)

Comment: @Mafii unless there's a very good reason to do otherwise I would prefer to see a class implement two separate interfaces than to have one interface implement another - there's no reason why implementing one of those methods should imply implementing the other. That is, I would prefer `Implementor : IMyInterface, IMyInterface2` to `Implementor : IMyInterface2` and `IMyInterface2 : IMyInterface`.

Comment: Yes, generally I agree, its obv. up to the situation! @AntP